# Is there a way to force a derived class to implement an abstract class or an interface nested in base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, overriding, abstract-class

I have this abstract class:

```
public abstract class Task
{
  public string ID {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public abstract class Options{};

  public abstract void Execute();
}
```

I have other classes extending this class:

```
public class Copy : Task
{
  public override void Execute()
  {
    Console.Write ("running");
  }
}
```

I'd like each derived class to implement their own **Options** class so they can have their own parameters.

So **Search** class have to implement it's own **Options** class with the properties it needs, such as "*includesubfolders*", "*casesensitive*", etc..

Meanwhile **Move** task can implement it's own: "*overwrite*", etc..

Making properties and methods abstract in an abstract class force derived classes to implement their own but defining a nested abstract class or an interface in the same class does not force it's derived classes implement their own.

I can define each property individually in each derived class but that defeats the purpose since I like to query the properties in Task.Options later in the Execute method.

I tried dynamic object as well, but that brought whole other issues.

Comment: An *abstract* nested class, this is why we can't have nice things...

Comment: Can you please show an example how the `Options` class is used in the abstract base class `Task`? If there is no such case you don't need to declare it in the base class.

Comment: No.  Nested classes work more like namespaces, which is why you can't enforce implementation.  It would be perfectly legal to implement `Task.Options` with a non-nested class!

Comment: @QualityCatalyst Options class is not used in the base class (I mean it doesn't define a method), the base class is used as an abstract class with couple of other defined methods. I have other classes that extend this class with all the properties ID, Name, Definition, etc.. I just need them to create another object that holds filtering data (I guess I can make a dictionary and store it there but I just want to know if I can do it this way). Thank you for your comment

Comment: If you don't need the `Options` class in the base class then don't try to force any inheriting class to think about it. If it is not needed in the base class and if there is no good reason to declare it just don't do it. What if there is a task that doesn't have options?

Comment: @DStanley yeah I did that but then I have to define properties in the Options class and every class that extend that class get all the properties regardless they are meant for that task class or not. I initialized all properties with their default values and ignored the ones not needed but then I thought this so I wanted to ask.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst I was thinking to still define the class but leave it empty with no properties.

Comment: @DStanley's answer is fairly good if you really need to force an inheriting class to have options. However, again, if there is no single use case where you use the options within the base class or where you use the options when dealing with instances that are declared to be tasks (e. g. `Task t = new Copy()` and then use something like `t.Options`) then simply don't force the inheriting classes to think about `Options`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generic

```
public abstract class Options{};

public class CopyOptions : Options
{
}

public abstract class Task<T> where T : Options
{
  public string ID {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}

  public T Options { get; set; }

  public abstract void Execute();
}

public class Copy : Task<CopyOptions>
{
    public override void Execute()
    {
        Console.Write("running");
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this, it does what I asked in my question. It creates another problem ,which is mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9140873/3481709), it still answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't enforce a nested class implementation, but you could add a *property* for the Options:

```
public abstract class Task
{
  public string ID {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public Options Options {get; set;}
  public abstract void Execute();

  public abstract class Options{};
}
```

However there's no way to enforce that the implementation of the `Options` class be nested within the class that implements `Task`.

Comment: Actually, you *can* force the `Options` class to be nested by making it `protected` rather than `public`, but that removes the ability to use the `Options` class outside `Task` and its descendents.

Answer (score 0):

You can always throw a notimplementedexeption exception

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32941032)