# How to unwrap object handle created with Activator.CreateInstance to the base class?

Tags: c#, derived-class, createinstance

In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28442519/3481709) I wanted to force all derived classes to implement their own options class. The given answer provided a solution to my problem but then created another problem as I couldn't unwrap the object handle anymore.

I have created an empty public interface and a class that implements it:

```
public interface IOptions{};

public class SearchOptions : IOptions
{
    public Boolean SearchHiddenFiles { get; set; }
    public Boolean CaseSensitive { get; set; }
}
```

Then I created a base class with an abstract parameter `TaskOptions` which is type of IOptions:

```
public abstract class Task<T> where T : IOptions
{
  public string ID {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}

  public abstract T TaskOptions { get; set; }
  public abstract void Execute();
}
```

And finally, I created bunch of classes which extend Task class, i.e.:

```
public class TaskSearch : Task <SearchOptions>
{
    public override SearchOptions TaskOptions { get; set; }
    public override void Execute()
    {
        Console.Write("Search running");
    }
}
```

The main program initializes a Job object which takes a file that has json notation that defines the id, name, etc.. along with tasks.

Lastly, here is the job class:

```
public class Job
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public List<Task<IParameters>> Tasks { get; set; }
    public Job(string JsonFile)
    {        
        using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(JsonFile))
        {
            string json = file.ReadToEnd();
            JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

            this.Name = o.SelectToken("Name").ToString();
            this.Description = o.SelectToken("Description").ToString();

            JArray arr = (JArray)o["Tasks"];

            foreach (var t in arr)
            {
                var taskclass = t["Name"].ToString();

                var taskobj = Activator.CreateInstance("RunTasks", "RunTasks." + taskclass);

                var task = (Task<IParameters>)taskobj.Unwrap(); //<-- throws System.InvalidCastException because taskobj is TaskSearch
                // set task.ID, task.Name, etc..
                //...
                //...
                Tasks.Add(task);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Before I changed the Task class to implement IOptions interface, I unwrapped it as:

```
var task = (Task)taskobj.Unwrap();
```

which worked but after adding `IOptions` and casting it to `Task<IOptions>` it throws System.InvalidCastException error because taskobj is TaskSearch (not Task).

If I manually type `Task<SearchOptions>` then it unwraps but then complains about the *Tasks* list at the end as it's now not type of `Task<IOptions>`.
I need to make the *Tasks* list generic so it accepts all derived classes and find a way to get type parameters before unwrapping taskobj or get it from *taskclass* string which holds the current task name.

I'll create a dictionary for the options if I have to but this is how I wanted to implement it and I'd like to know if I can.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of implicitly defining task object, I defined it explicitly as dynamic type.

```
dynamic task = taskobj.Unwrap();
```

Without casting, compiler does not complain about it because it's dynamic and it knows it's TaskSearch during runtime.