# C# Covert Type into IEnumerable of same Type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I have some methods that execute arbitrary SQL against a database and serialize that data collection into a list of a concrete type. That data is then serialized into JSON and stored in a cell in a table. Later, I need to come back and deserialize that data back into its original collection so that it can be used.

I'm having some issues figuring out how to take a `Type` object and create a collection of that type in order to deserialize it. Here is how my code operates:

```
public async Task ExecuteWidget(Guid runGuid, string widgetName, Type type, string sql,
    IEnumerable<SqlParameter> parameters)
{
    var report = operationsContext.ReportRuns.FirstOrDefault(n => n.RunGuid == runGuid);

    CheckReportStatus(report);

    var param = parameters.ToList();
    var result = edwContext.Database.SqlQuery(type, sql, param.ToArray<object>());
    var query = result.GetQuery(param);
    var data = await result.ToListAsync();
    var widgetData = new ReportRunWidgetData()
    {
        ReportRunId = report?.ReportRunId ?? -1, // This should never be null.
        WidgetName = widgetName,
        WidgetData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data),
        Query = query
    };

    operationsContext.ReportRunWidgetDatas.Add(widgetData);
    await operationsContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

My fetching logic looks something like this:

```
public object FetchWidgetData(Guid runGuid, string widgetName, Type dataType)
{
    var data = operationsContext.ReportRuns
        .Include("ReportRunWidgetDatas")
        .FirstOrDefault(n => n.RunGuid == runGuid)?
        .ReportRunWidgetDatas.FirstOrDefault(n => n.WidgetName == widgetName)?
        .WidgetData;

    if (data == null) return null;

    var deserialized = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(data, dataType);

    return deserialized;
}
```

Now when the `ExecuteWidget` method is called, the `type` parameter is populated by the widget's DTO datatype. For example `HeadlineWidgetDTO`. However, the execute command gets the data back as a `List<HeadlineWidgetDTO>`. When my `FetchWidgetData` method is called, the `dataType` supplied is still `HeadlineWidgetDTO`, but it actually needs to be of type `IEnumerable<HeadlineWidgetDTO>` to deserialize properly.

Given just the type for an individual data row, how can I create a `Type` object that is instead a collection of that type?

Comment: FYI `List<T>` deserialization is supported in Json.NET, which is what you _should_ be using.  Microsoft's [own documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) tells you to use Json.NET for serializing/deserializing

Comment: @maccettura that still doesn't address how to go from a `Type` for `HeadlineWidgetDTO` to `IEnumerable<HeadlineWidgetDTO>`. I do not believe Json.Net will handle that for me.

Comment: Is this what you are talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140873/how-to-use-activator-to-create-an-instance-of-a-generic-type-and-casting-it-back ?  You can use `Type.MakeGenericType` and `Activator.CreateInstance` to create a `List<T>` from a `T`

Comment: @Flydog57 precisely. If you want to craft that into an answer, I'll go ahead and mark it.

Comment: Also in EF Core you can embed your JSON serializer into a Value Conversion https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

Comment: @JDDavis: I added another way to do this to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly a duplicate of [How to use Activator to create an instance of a generic Type and casting it back to that type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140873/how-to-use-activator-to-create-an-instance-of-a-generic-type-and-casting-it-back), however it's hard to tell.

Basically, if you have a type object `Type theType`, you need to do something like:

```
 var listType = typeof(List<>);
 var typeParams = new [] {theType};
 var listOfTType = listType.MakeGenericType(typeParams);
 var newListOfT = Activator.CreateInstance(listOfTType);
```

At that point, you have a variable of type `object`, but that references an object of type `List<WhateverYourTypeIs>`.  Say, `theType` is `typeof(int)`, then you will have an object of `List<int>`.  Casting it to something usuable is a whole other question though.  If you want to add something to that list, I suspect the best way would be to get a `MethodInfo` for the `Add` method and `Invoke` it.

I thought of another way to do this if the type has a default constructor and isn't too expensive to create.  Here's a sample (creating a `List<int>` - but that's just the way I have it coded):

```
  var type = typeof(int);
  var dummy = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
  var listOfType = new[] {dummy}.ToList();
```

When you are finished, the `listOfType` variable is typed as a `List<object>` but refers to a `List<int>`.  It's mostly mostly workable - for example, you can call `Add(object someObj)` on it.  You won't get compile type parameter type checking, but you will be able to use it.